# Is Geb's ultimate effected by protections?

Tags: smite

Geb's [Cataclysm](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Geb) has the rather unique feature of dealing damage based on a percentage of target health, instead of a number like pretty much every other skill. Is this lowered by protections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Geb pulls apart the earth, dealing magical damage to all enemy gods based on 15/20/25/30/35% of their current health, and stunning them for 1/1.2/1.4/1.6/1.8s.*

This skill deals magical damage, **not** a reduction of health like Nemesis' ultimate. The total damage dealt is affected by the affected enemies' magical protection.